# Is there a way to disable mouse player looking in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am following a unity tutorial (brackeys pause menu) and when i pause the game, the player cant move but can still look around. (FPS) here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume( );
            }
            else
            {
                Pause ();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume ()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }
    void Pause ()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
```

and the player script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkingSpeed = 7.5f;
    public float runningSpeed = 11.5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float lookXLimit = 45.0f;

    CharacterController characterController;
    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    float rotationX = 0;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool canMove = true;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        // Lock cursor
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate move direction based on axes
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        // Press Left Shift to run
        bool isRunning = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        float curSpeedX = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
        float curSpeedY = canMove ? (isRunning ? runningSpeed : walkingSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
        float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (forward * curSpeedX) + (right * curSpeedY);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canMove && characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection.y = movementDirectionY;
        }

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        // Player and Camera rotation
        if (canMove)
        {
            rotationX += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed;
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSpeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

the mouse is getting moved around the menu and the player is picking up the input. i wanted to stop it (maybe using a bool?) but ive tried.

Comment: You probably just want to check for `if(!PauseMenu.GameIsPaused)` ...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that canMove is ever assigned a value other than true. This could be your problem as if you code works, the player will only move if canMove is true and as it is not set to false anywhere the player will always move.

To test this you can change the line, public bool canMove = true; to public bool canMove = false;

Comment: no, thats not the issue, its the mouse input and player looking